# requireActivity() or get application context when instantiating WorkManager in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been doing some with a fragment that has a view model with a dependency on the WorkManager. I used to get the WorkManager using the now deprecated method `WorkManager.getInstance()`, so I refactored the code and followed the same method of getting the WorkManager instance as that done in the Sunflower project ([which has since changed](https://github.com/android/sunflower/commit/15c17da9dc19f4c03f81064901d937d00fe86b85#diff-b6cfc69c5f21d0cf70268c65b0692313)). The Sunflower sample project now uses NavArgs() and no longer does this: `InjectorUtils.providePlantDetailViewModelFactory(requireActivity(), args.plantId)`

My question is, can `IllegalStateException` be thrown when assigning the viewModel variable by injection because of getting a WorkManager instance using requireActivity() like in my code below? Is it possible for an activity to not be attached/get destroyed at the time this variable is assigned? Should I refactor and use the application context instead of requireActivity()?

```
class DetailFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel by inject<ViewModel> { parametersOf(WorkManager.getInstance(requireActivity())) }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        viewDataBinding = DetailFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
            vm = viewModel.apply {
                event.observe(this@DetailFragment, Observer {
                    viewDataBinding.refreshLayout.isRefreshing = false
                })
            }
        }

        return viewDataBinding.root
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be mostly safe. But it only depends on where you get `viewModel` for the first time. You could make sure `viewModel` gets initialized in `onCreate` or `onStart` before setting up any handler accessing it.

In your case it's called in `onCreateView` only, thus it should be attached to an `Activity` and for that reason safe.

Comment: I've updated my original question to include the contents of OnCreateView

Comment: I've updated the answer. You should be safe with that.